# File missing from java.library.path

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, rxtx

I am building an app to get NMEA GPS data, with serial port communication via RXTX.
On my Mac it runs great. When I try to run it on my Rasp Pi, it throws the error:

```
no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
```

On the Mac, I see that if I move /Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib it too throws the same error.

My question is: On my RasbPi, do I need to add this rxtxSerial file somewhere to a folder (perhaps within the JVM?), or should it be packaged up with the runnable jar when I export. Is my problem on my Mac, or on my RasbPi?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can install this library on the Raspberry Pi via the normal package installation method.

Just type:

```
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java
```

Now you can start the jar like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar -jar your.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that a native library named `rxtxSerial` cannot be found. You need to have a native library for the Raspberry Pi with that name, and set the system property `java.library.path` so that it points to the directory that contains the native library. That means you have to start your Java program with the `-D` option, for example:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/some/dir com.mypackage.MyProgram
```

where `/some/dir` is the directory that contains the native library.

You'll have to find out if there is a native library that is suitable for the Raspberry Pi for the RXTX library that you are trying to use.